# Optimize the performance of the function in python

Tags: python, for-loop, optimization

I need to extract a value from A based on B, but using a for-loop becomes impractical with a large dataset. While the code below avoids using a for-loop, it still takes the same amount of time.

```py
import numpy as np

# Given matrices A and B
A = np.array([[254, 0, 0],
              [109, 0, 1],
              [126, 0, 2],
              [66, 0, 3],
              [220, 1, 0],
              [98, 1, 1],
              [230, 1, 2],
              [17, 1, 3],
              [83, 2, 0],
              [106, 2, 1],
              [123, 2, 2],
              [57, 2, 3]])

B = np.array([[1, 2],
              [0, 1],
              [1, 0],
              [1, 1],
              [-1, 2],
              [1, 3],
              [1, 1],
              [0, 0],
              [2, 2],
              [1, 0],
              [2, 3],
              [0, 1]])

## these two functions give the same results.
def get_pixel2d(A, B): 
    corresponding_rows = np.all(A[:, 1:3] == B[:, None], axis=-1)
    get_pixel_final = (corresponding_rows * A[:, 0]).sum(axis=1)
    return get_pixel_final

# this is more faster
def get_pixel2d(A, B):
    corresponding_rows = np.all(A[:, 1:3] == B[:, None], axis=-1)
    get_pixel_final = np.sum(A[:, 0] * corresponding_rows, axis=1)
    return get_pixel_final

result = get_pixel2d(A, B)
print(result)

[230 109 220  98   0  17  98 254 123 220  57 109]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transform your lookup table and then use normal indexing + `np.where` (I recommend to transform the lookup table (`A`) before to speed things up even further):

```py
def get_pixel2d_3(A, B):
    a, b = np.max(A[:, 1]), np.max(A[:, 2])

    lookup_table = np.zeros((a + 1, b + 1), dtype=np.uint8)
    lookup_table[A[:, 1], A[:, 2]] = A[:, 0]

    m1 = (B[:, 0] >= 0) & (B[:, 0] <= a)
    m2 = (B[:, 1] >= 0) & (B[:, 1] <= b)
    m = m1 & m2

    return np.where(m, lookup_table[B[:, 0], B[:, 1]], 0)
```

---

Benchmark:

```py
import perfplot

perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: (A, np.tile(B, (n, 1))),
    kernels=[
        get_pixel2d,
        get_pixel2d_2,
        get_pixel2d_3,
    ],
    labels=["get_pixel2d", "get_pixel2d_2", "get_pixel2d_3"],
    n_range=[1, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000],
    xlabel="N",
    equality_check=lambda a, b: np.all(a == b),
    logx=True,
    logy=True,
)
```

Creates this graph:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the @ operator to perform matrix multiplication instead of element-wise multiplication and sum. This can be faster and more concise. For example, you can rewrite your function as:

```
def get_pixel2d(A, B):
    corresponding_rows = np.all(A[:, 1:3] == B[:, None], axis=-1)
    get_pixel_final = corresponding_rows @ A[:, 0]
    return get_pixel_final
```

You can use numpy broadcasting to avoid creating a new array with None. This can save some memory and computation. For example, you can rewrite your function as:

```
def get_pixel2d(A, B):
    corresponding_rows = np.all(A[:, 1:3][..., None] == B.T, axis=1)
    get_pixel_final = corresponding_rows @ A[:, 0]
    return get_pixel_final
```

You can use numpy vectorization to avoid using a loop or a function call. This can make your code more readable and faster. For example, you can rewrite your code as:

```
get_pixel_final = np.all(A[:, 1:3][..., None] == B.T, axis=1) @ A[:, 0]
print(get_pixel_final)
```

Comment: Hey @Ayushh, thanks for the answer. However, only the first one gives me the result that I expect.